# convert NSString TO NSNumber accurately with decimal

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4, ios6

Lets say my string value is as follows
12345.12
after converting it to NSNumber its coming as 12345.1223122
But I want the accurate number from string
Is there a way to achieve it.
Code that I'm using right now

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:aString];
    [f release];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're dealing with currency-type numbers (just a guess from your use of the currency style formatter) you probably want to use [`NSDecimalNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDecimalNumber). Unlike standard floating point types, decimal numbers use a base-10 exponent so that you always get exactly the expected accuracy when dealing with money problems — i.e. they're the same as using integers and then moving the decimal point around in the base-10 representation.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[f setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:aString];
[f release];
NSLog(@"%@",myNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this...

```
 NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSNumber * myNumber=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[f numberFromString:aString] floatValue]];
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a few years, but this works:

```
double d = [@"123.45" doubleValue];
NSNumber* n = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:d];
```